# Redirect all pages to the home except two pages

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The root directory is the file index.php and .htaccess configuration file. How to make a 301 redirect all URLs in the / (main page) but URL'a with the string http: //mysite.loc/1, http: //mysite.loc/2 and http: //mysite.loc /?

For example:

```
http: //mysite.loc/ (URL available, show index.php)
http: //mysite.loc/1 (URL available, show index.php)
http: //mysite.loc/2 (URL available, show index.php)
http: //mysite.loc/testing (301 redirect on /)
http: //mysite.loc/qwerty (301 redirect on /)
```

The problem lies in the infinite redirects to the main page.

Note: You must create a rule only in the configuration file .htaccess, PHP-scripts can not be used.

All available URL leads to / (index.php file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule !^(1|2|index\.php)?/?$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(1|2)?/?$ index.php [L]
```

Clear browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: This works, but it is necessary to mysite.loc / send displays the contents of the index.php

Comment: Excuse me, mysite.loc/1 or mysite.loc/2 show index.php

Comment: Three addresses 1) mysite.loс 2) mysite.loс/1 3) mysite.loс/2 must demonstrate one and the content from file index.php.

Comment: Redirect to /. Because this URL is not a / or /1 or /2.

Comment: By analogy to be processed URL /testing. The site should be allowed only three URL showing the same content. The rest of the URL redirect to /.

Comment: Almost right. But the URL /index.php should not be available. There must be a redirect to /.

Comment: Working! Thank you so much for helping me out today. A few days thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(1|2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The server forwards the request to this address so that it will never end. I have the same error :)

Comment: Most likely need RewriteCond% {ENV: REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$. But as long as I do not understand how to apply it.